# Is my tenancy invalid if my guarantor doesn't sign the agreement?

Tags: tenant, rent, tenancy-rules

I have recently signed a tenancy agreement (England) and have now decided I do not wish to live there. My guarantor has not yet signed their guarantor agreement. Does this make my tenancy agreement void? Also if I do not pay the rent does this make myself or my guarantor liable?

Comment: Did you actually move there? The terms of the agreement matter, at least those referring to the guarantor. I wish you elaborated on the issue, since one would need to make assumptions which might not be applicable to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

> I have recently signed a tenancy agreement (England) and have now
>   decided I do not wish to live there. My guarantor has not yet signed
>   their guarantor agreement. Does this make my tenancy agreement void?

No. At most, it makes it voidable by the landlord if the landlord doesn't want to enter into a lease unless you have a guarantee (assuming you have delivered your signed copy to the landlord or the landlord's agent, merely signing it is not effective until the signature is delivered).

> Also if I do not pay the rent does this make myself or my guarantor
>   liable?

A guarantor can't be held liable without a signature under the statute of frauds. But, you could be if you signed and delivered the lease to the landlord and the landlord didn't decline to accept you as a tenant for lack of a guarantor.